# Segment Button is not displaying on the navigation bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hello 
I am having problem in displaying segmented button on the navigation bar 
I try this code it's not working 
I have the Tab Bar For calling this tabBar I use
This code TabBar is working fine but Button on the navigation bar is not displaying

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITabBarController *tabcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UITabBarController *vc1 = [[TMapViewController alloc] init];
    UITabBarController *vc2 = [[TShareController alloc]init];
    UITabBarController *vc3 = [[TSpeedometerController alloc]init];
    UITabBarController *vc4 = [[TReviewsController alloc]init];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4,nil];



    [tabcontroller setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];
    [vc3 release];
    [vc4 release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: tabcontroller animated: YES];
}
```

And right this code into the TMapViewController.m for calling 
The button onto the navigation bar

```
-(id)init 
{
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
    [tbi setTitle:@"Map"];
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapper_f.png"];
    [tbi setImage:i];


    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Activitieslist.png"],

                                             nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 35);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
    [segmentBarItem release];

    return self;
}
```

Same thing i use into the 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Activitieslist.png"],

                                         nil]];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 35);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
[segmentBarItem release];
[[self.navigationBar topItem] setTitleView:segmentedControl]; 
[[[self.navigationBar topItem] titleView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 



TLocationManager *manager = [[TLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager = manager;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[manager release];

TMapRoutes *routes = [[TMapRoutes alloc] init];
self.mapRoutes = routes;
self.mapRoutes.mapView = self.myMapView;
[routes release];

self.myMapView.delegate = self;

/* Run the simulator */
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}
even it not work it give me same error .
Thanks in advance
Harish

Comment: I don't think I got your problem properly. Sorry I can't be of help further here.

Comment: When i don't use the tab it display the segmentBarItem >it mean when i call the other view directly with the navigation Push view thought it work is display the segment item but when call all the tab item it not display the segment item but Tabbar is workinng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it as `[self.navigationBar titleView:segmentedControl]`

```
-(void)loadView { 
 UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
    [tbi setTitle:@"Map"];
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapper_f.png"];
    [tbi setImage:i];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Activitieslist.png"],

                                         nil]];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 35);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];

[[self.navigationBar topItem] setTitleView:segmentedControl]; [[[self.navigationBAr topItem] titleView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[segmentBarItem release];
```

Comment: i use this into the -(id)init methods{all code this  [self.navigationBar titleView:segmentedControl];  }it give me error  request for member 'navigationBar' in something not a structure or union

Comment: try this way, 
[[self.navigationBar topItem] setTitleView:segmentedControl];
  [[[self.navigationBAr topItem] titleView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Comment: Don't write in init method. write the entire code in loadview method.

Comment: @ Anand look above I make change

Comment: What I mean to say is. In init method navigation controller will be not created it will be created in loadview  and you are trying to set the object for it. hence you are getting error.

Comment: Your answer is right that's way i am selecting your answer .But i done with other way I manually add the button on the navigationbar.Thank you for answer

Comment: But can you explain me how to replace the Navigation bar Button with other button

Comment: same as above. [[self.navigationBar topItem] setRightBarButton:buttonview];